# Sputtering Avocado Oil at High Temps

Tags: food-safety, oil, frying, heat, avocados

I recently purchased avocado oil from Costco, specifically Marianne's Harvest Brands Avocado Oil. I've tried frying/sauteing with it a couple of times, and so far, every time I've heated it up, it started sputtering badly. Is this common?

I imagined it would heat up like Canola or Vegetable oil, smooth and glassy, but as soon as it got hot enough, it started sputtering like crazy! The only thing I can think of is that I put the oil in a recently washed marasca bottle before pouring it into the pan.

Has anybody else had any issues with sputtering avocado oil when heating it up?

Comment: Sputtering generally means there's water present. If your bottle wasn't dry that's probably the source of the problem. Try pouring a bit of oil out from the original bottle and see if you get sputtering.

Comment: *OT* I'd never heard of marasca before, but I did at first wonder why you'd put cooking oil in a tiny eye make-up bottle ;)) serves me right for not reading more carefully/

Comment: @Tetsujin me too!  I was like, wait, are you sure that bottle is food safe?

Comment: Also ... @GdD that's an answer, post it?

Comment: I've been away so just got around to it @FuzzyChef.

Answer (score 3):

Sputtering usually means there's water present, so your oil must have some sort of water contamination. It's probably condensation left over from washing your bottle. You can determine this by pouring in some oil from the original bottle. If it doesn't spurt then you simply didn't dry the marasca bottle well enough, if it does your oil has been contaminated and you should take it back.

If it's only the bottle that has some water in it there's nothing to worry about, you could heat it up and slowly get the water out of it but I suggest you just leave it and accept it's going to spurt.

Comment: You might be able to recover the oil by slowly heating so the water evaporates, letting it cook, then putting it back into a dry bottle.  It’s basically the process that you’d use for schmaltz if you rendered it when poaching chicken.

Comment: True @Joe, but if there's water in there it points to a problem with manufacturing or storage, it makes more sense to take it back.

Comment: I was suggesting it for the bit that they had transferred to a different bottle